# Passing 2 arrays from controller to view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass two arrays from controller to view, using this approach:

My underlying data query has extracted this data as follows:
$catalogData: Title (Clothing); Season (Winter);
$ProductData: Type (Shirts); Size (XL); Price ($10);

Controller

```
$this->load->view('users/TheView', $catalogData,  $productData);
```

View

```
<?php 
echo $Catalog;
echo $Season;
echo $Type;
echo $Size; 
echo $Price; 
?>
```

My error message is

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: Catalog
Filename: users/controller.php
```

I cant seem to find any examples of passing two arrays to a view, which makes me think it's not possible?

Edit: I'm using CodeIgniter

Comment: I suggest you read the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html) next time (see `$this->load->view('file_name', $data, true/false)`)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP didn't bother to consult the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I don't see anything specific that I'm mentioning, but I'll give it another go.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything about the MVC framework in question, I can only assume it expects one array argument after the view name and uses [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/function.extract.php), in which case I'd do the following

```
$this->load->view('users/TheView', array(
    'catalog' => $catalogData,
    'product' => $productData));
```

and in your view...

```
<?php
echo $catalog['Title'], $catalog['Season'], $product['Type'], etc
```

Also, your error message seems to indicate that you should be using `$Title` instead of `$Catalog`. `Title` is the property name shown in your data example.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm obviously missing something else. Doesn't change my error of "undefined variable"

Comment: @Maxcot And where **exactly** in my answer do you see any use of an array index *Catalog*?

Comment: I just don't how to answer you. I'm still trying to learn this stuff. But thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: @Maxcot You say the error is about an undefined index *Catalog*. In my answer, I use `'Title'`, not `'Catalog'`. Unless the error is from a part of your code you haven't posted yet, you're simply using the wrong index name.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is if you want to pass more than one array to view then you should do something like this in controller

```
$data=array();
$data['catalogData']=$this->model_name->function_name(); // query for catalog
$data['ProductData']=$this->model_name->function_name(); // query for product
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```

in view

```
if(isset($catalogData) && is_array($catalogData) && count($catalogData)>0)
{
    echo $catalogData['Title'];
}
```

these is the procedure.Please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple different thing I can think of,

First: you are trying to echo $Catalog, but I don't see anywhere that you are passing a variable with that name to your view. This leads to the second part.

Second: You need to echo out the object you are trying to print, not the Array. so they should be something like:

```
<?php echo $catalogData['Title']; ?>
```

Finally, I honestly never do php programing without a framework, and you don;t mention if you are using one, but typically in those you pass an array of variables into your view. So something like:

```
$this->load->view('users/TheView', array('catalogData'=>$catalogData, 'productData'=>$productData);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it's CodeIgniter. And yep , the typos around title are easily fixed. Tried your suggestion (with some corrections to missing brackets etc) but just changes the error message to "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: I'm not sure if codeIgnitor can use the Array->item syntax. edited my answer to the more common bracket form.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass two arrays like this

```
$data['catalogData']    =   $catalogData;
$data['productData']    =   $productData;

$this->load->view('users/TheView', $data);
```